# Value of type 'System.Uri' cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to change `system.uri` to string and then to integer?
I want to use `webcontrol.source` as file name in windows.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TextBox1.Text = (WebControl1.Source)
End Sub
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sample of conversion (like `http://www.msn.com` -> msn -> 16) would help... Otherwise in current state the post is very unclear and likely end up being closed.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more?How to change System.Uri  to string?

Comment: How can I explain what *you* are asking about? Maybe you are looking for `.ToString` method - how would I know?

Comment: I used awesomium web control and want to save a file in my computer with `webcontrol.source` . i mean save file name as website that awesomium is navigating.

Comment: You can convert `WebControl1.Source` to a string by using its `.ToString` method. For example: `TextBox1.Text = WebControl1.Source.ToString` I can't, however, figure out why you'd want to try to convert that to an integer.

Comment: It works, thank you man.Im new and used `textbox1.text = ToString(webcontrol1.source)` instead of `textbox1.text = TextBox1.Text = (WebControl1.Source.ToString)`. I want to use this string as file name in windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox1.Text = WebControl1.Source.ToString
```

Comment: Self-answer is ok as long as both Q and A are reasonable quality and on-topic. Please make sure to change your question to match your answer (and consider actually explaining what you've asked/answered).

Comment: My English is awful :( if you can help me with Q i can edit that. but i got my answer.